# Overcome floating points precision oracle + c#, any workaround?

Tags: c#, oracle, precision

I use C# and Oracle.DataAccess with stored procedure, that build the DataSet
automatically from query results.
i need workaround this problem **without need to do Round()** (this solve the issue) to all my queries.

In the DB I have a NUMBER(10,2) type field named TotalPayout and when dumping it on the DB I get this data

```
select a.totalpayout, DUMP(a.totalpayout)    from   tbla a    where a.totalpayout > 17 and a.totalpayout < 18;
```

returns:

TOTALPAYOUT , DUMP(A.TOTALPAYOUT)

- 17.40            , Typ=2 Len=3: 193,18,41
- 17.50            , Typ=2 Len=3: 193,18,51
- 17.60            , Typ=2 Len=3: 193,18,61
- 17.70            , Typ=2 Len=3: 193,18,71

But when running the progrem on the DataSet into column type Double I get this values

Total Payout

- 17.400000000000002
- 17.5
- 17.7
- 17.6

The first value get extra 00000000000002
Can’t find any clue why this happening.

this is the code i use to get the data

```
  public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(OracleConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params OracleParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        if (connection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");

        // Create a command and prepare it for execution
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        bool mustCloseConnection = false;
        PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, (OracleTransaction)null, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection);

        // Create the DataAdapter & DataSet
        using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            // Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
            da.Fill(ds);

            // Detach the OracleParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            if (mustCloseConnection)
                connection.Close();

            // Return the dataset
            return ds;
        }
    }
```

If anyone has any workaround  I would appreciate it. Would really like to fix this issue, **without repairing all the queries**.

Comment: Don't use floating points. Use Decimals. The clue is that you're using floating point numbers.

Comment: As Sami said. The problem is caused in C#, NOT IN ORACLE!  The problem is caused by the fact that computers normally work in binary, and 1/10 in binary is an infinite periodic decimal (due to the factor 5, which is not a power of 2). You will ALWAYS get this kind of issues if you use float or double. In engineering and scientific computations that is no problem, but if in your application it is a problem, use the DECIMAL data type, that's why it was created in the first place.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, if you see the code i use da.Fill(ds); with build the Dataset Dynamically, need workaround for this.

Comment: Can you create a view of the data in oracle which performs some sort of cast to convert to a more reliable data type?

Comment: Or make the column an object and handle its contents accordingly with an OracleDecimal data type.